# Three random points on a circle

Tags: java, geometry, points

I'm trying to create a program where three random points in a circle are created and result in the creation of an inscribed triangle.  However, the angles I'm getting are all screwed up

Here is my code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double r = 40.0;
        double angle1 = Math.random()* (2 * Math.PI);
        double angle2 = Math.random()* (2 * Math.PI);
        double angle3 = Math.random()* (2 * Math.PI);
        double x_1 = r * Math.cos(angle1); 
        double y_1 = r * Math.sin(angle1);
        double x_2 = r * Math.cos(angle2); 
        double y_2 = r * Math.sin(angle2);
        double x_3 = r * Math.cos(angle3); 
        double y_3 = r * Math.sin(angle3);
        System.out.println("The coordinates of the three points are: 
        (" + x_1 +                 ", " + y_1 + ") 
        (" + x_2 + ", " + y_2 + ") 
        (" + x_3 + ", " + y_3 + ")");
    //Get length of each side
    double distanceFrom1To2 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x_2 - x_1, 2) + 
    Math.pow(y_2 - y_1, 2));
    double distanceFrom2To3 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x_3 - x_2, 2) + 
    Math.pow(y_3 - y_2, 2));
    double distanceFrom3To1 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x_1 - x_3, 2) + 
    Math.pow(y_1 - y_3, 2));
    //Get angles ***
    double triangleAngle1 = Math.atan(distanceFrom1To2 / distanceFrom2To3);
    double triangleAngle2 = Math.atan(distanceFrom2To3 / distanceFrom3To1);
    double triangleAngle3 = Math.atan(distanceFrom3To1 / distanceFrom1To2);
    System.out.println("The three angles are " + triangleAngle1 + " " + 
    triangleAngle2 + " " + triangleAngle3);
    System.out.println(triangleAngle1 + triangleAngle2 + triangleAngle3);
}
```

I definitely know that the means of getting the angles are screwed up.  Here is a sample run of my program:

```
    The coordinates of the three points are: (5.224534224725408,  
    -39.65733528787168) (-29.696946087404676, 26.79722733944279) 
    (32.70889681040468, -23.02451018906371)

    The three angles are 0.7545364726122026 1.18830825410364 
    0.40435068059871415
    Total angle sum: 2.347195407314557
```

The angles all add up to much greater than Pi / 2 radians.  I've considered the law of sines but you have to know at least one angle for that...

Comment: You need to use [`atan2`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan2(double,%20double)) instead of `atan` for your angles. I'm assuming this is Java, you should tag your questions with a language - but the advice holds no matter what language.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out

Here is the fixed code:

```
    //Get length of each side
    double a = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x_2 - x_1, 2) + Math.pow(y_2 - y_1, 2)); // distance from 1 to 2
    double b = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x_3 - x_2, 2) + Math.pow(y_3 - y_2, 2)); // distance from 2 to 3
    double c = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x_1 - x_3, 2) + Math.pow(y_1 - y_3, 2)); // distance from 3 to 1
    //Get angles ***
    double triangleAngle1 = Math.acos((Math.pow(a, 2) + Math.pow(b, 2) - Math.pow(c, 2)) / (2 * a * b));
    double triangleAngle2 = Math.acos((Math.pow(b, 2) + Math.pow(c, 2) - Math.pow(a, 2)) / (2 * c * b));
    double triangleAngle3 = Math.acos((Math.pow(c, 2) + Math.pow(a, 2) - Math.pow(b, 2)) / (2 * a * c));
```

I changed it to use the law of cosines.